Retrieve all implementations of an interface with a specific property value
I have the following code in Typescript:
interface Foo {
    readonly name: string;
};

const FOO_1: Foo = {
    name: 'zing'
};

const FOO_2: Foo = {
    name: 'baz'
};

Is there a way to retrieve all implementations of Foo such that I can filter by name, without storing the constants in a separate list? For example, I want to get all implementations of Foo with name zing. This would return FOO_1.


Is there a way to retrieve all implementations of Foo such that I can filter by name, without storing the constants in a separate list?

No, there isn't. There is no way to get a list of the local bindings (variables, constants, etc.) in a scope. If you exported them from a module, you could use the module namespace object, but that would be fairly dodgy (and you're not exporting them, so it doesn't apply). Best to put them in a list explicitly as you mentioned.
